# Writing a single Reducer for multiple Componenets

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I wrote 2 class components, and a single reducer to be used by both components using `mapStateToProps`.

Component A reducer def:

```
import notify from '../global/reducers/notifyReducer';

const compAReducer = combineReducers({
    notify
});

export default compAReducer;
```

Component B reducer def:

```
import notify from  '../global/reducers/notifyReducer';

const compBReducer = combineReducers({
    notify
});

export default compBReducer;
```

The reducer looks like this:

```
import * as types from '../../../actions/actionTypes';

export default function notifyReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.NOTIFY_SUCCESS:
        case types.NOTIFY_FAILURE:
            return action.notify;
        case types.NOTIFY_NULL:
            return {};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when a compnent A dispatches an action, it affects the state of component B, vice verca.

This is not the behaviour i'm looking for. I wish that the component will use the same logic, but will hold a different "state property".
A different "notify" instance.

Is it possible, or do I have to duplicate the reducer?

Thanks a lot. I'm still learning React-Redux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can namespace your state, by giving each component an ID.

```
export function notifyReducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
        case types.NOTIFY_SUCCESS:
        case types.NOTIFY_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, [action.id]: action.notify };
        case types.NOTIFY_NULL:
            return { ...state, [action.id]: {} };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is make sure that your component includes the `id` property with each action it dispatches.

Depending on your application, there may already be a logical ID associated with each instance of your component, otherwise you can generate a random one inside the constructor.

```
import uid from 'uid';

constructor() {
  super(this);
  this.id = uid();
}
```

Then each of your action creators should accept `id` as a parameter.

```
function notifyFailure(id, notify) {
  return { id, type: types.NOTIFY_FAILURE, notify }
}
```

And finally, you need to pass the ID through when you `mapDispatchToProps`.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    notifyFailure(id, notify) {
      dispatch(notifyFailure(id, notify));
    }
  }
}
```

Or use [`bindActionCreators`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html) if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but actually is does not work. It state still getting update in both components (so after dispatching the action, they also hold the same id).
also, if before I wished the state of notify to be a simple string for displaying a message, now it's an object with id as a key and the string as the value, it's not declarative, and pretty strange.
I'll read more about it.. thanks

Comment: Just because the data is slightly more complex does not mean that it is no longer declarative. It might not be as simple as you would like it to be, but wrapping data in an object with an id is not at all strange.

Comment: You are totally right- there are tons of advantages for this approach. But I wanted the state to stay simple- just a simple string. I'm trying to make the view, pretty much as the mirror of the state. and notify's message should be.. just a string. 
Actually I solved it using a customised high-order reduces:
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html
So now I can target specific areas of the state, without adding additional identifiers to it (on the actual store level)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually went with the high order reducers approach:

[You can read about it here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html)

import * as types from '../../../actions/actionTypes';

```
export default function createNotifyReducerWithPageType(pageType = '') {
    return function notifyReducer(state = '', action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case types.NOTIFY_SUCCESS + `_${pageType}`:
            case types.NOTIFY_FAILURE + `_${pageType}`:
                return action.notify;
            case types.NOTIFY_NULL:
                return {};
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
}
```

action creators:

```
export function notifySuccess(notify, type) {
    return {
        type: types.NOTIFY_SUCCESS + type,
        notify
    }
}

export function notifyFailure(notify, type) {
    return {
        type: types.NOTIFY_FAILURE + type,
        notify
    }
}
```

reducers:

```
import createNotifyReducerWithPageType from '../global/reducers/notifyReducer';

const compA = combineReducers({
    notify: createNotifyReducerWithPageType('_compA')
});

export default compA;
```

and the second one:

```
import createNotifyReducerWithPageType from '../global/reducers/notifyReducer';

const compB = combineReducers({
    notify: createNotifyReducerWithPageType('_compB')
});

export default compB;
```

So now the states' structure is the same, as the actions creators take care of directing the behaviour.